# NoClassDefFoundError when using org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringSerializer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, websphere, java-7

I have just started with Kafka in a Java 1.7 app that will run on WebSphere 8.5. The project builds just fine. I deploy it to WebSphere and run it and get this error:

```
 Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringSerializer
```

This is a Java Maven project with this in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code is pretty simple as a basic first test:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "chdhadoopd05:6667");
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    
    KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    
    ProducerRecord<String, String> record=new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my_test", "Hi Kafka");
    
    kafkaProducer.send(record);
    kafkaProducer.flush();
    kafkaProducer.close();
```

I've read dozens of posts and questions, all each a little different, and so far I'm not seeing any solution. Does my code above look correct? Am I missing anything? Do I need to do something to the server?

Comment: Check if your kafka-clients jar is in war/ear that you are building. Also afaik Kafka no longer supports Java7, so either look for older libraries that support that or update your Java in WebSphere and see if it helps.

Comment: I don't have websphere experience, but I think you do need to modify its classpath to add dependencies. Otherwise, by default, maven doesn't do that for your war/jar

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found deep inside the docs on one page...  Apache Kofka 2.x removed support for Java 7. I downgraded to v. 1.x and the error went away.